# JPA and foreign key constraints

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I heard about the fact that we are able to create the whole JPA entity structure based on an existing database. Now, having existing foreign key constraints:

Now let me define a simple member, e.g. as follows:

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", 
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE}) 
 private List<UserGroup> userGroups;
```

Is this reference handled with a foreign key or with the existing logic, i.e. by running two query or more subsequent queries within a transaction.

The question is: Am I allowed to define foreign keys to run native query in a fast matter while keeping the system in a consistent state? I don't want to abstain from JPA entity management in many situations.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking if you're allowed to have a foreign key contraint on UserGroup.userId, referencing User.id? If so, of course you can. You should.

Comment: Yes of course, i.e. I have to add constraints? Thought this would bring some issues since a database constraint would mean that the db handles the relationsships (e.g. automatically remove dependent entities) and the annotation-way would let the provider manage them.

Comment: No. A constraint doesn't cause the database to automatically remove the dependent entities. To the contrary: it prevents the deletion of the referenced row if it's still referenced by a foreign key.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. So I will definitively create constraints in the future :)